How to collect the terms with $m_1$ in common, $m_2$ in common and $m_3$ in common in a large expression?
How do I separate the terms in the following expression having $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$? Please help me out. I shall be really grateful.
1/2 E^(-2 I \[Delta]) (2 (Cos[\[Theta]13]^2 (m1 Cos[\[Theta]12]^2 + E^(2 I \[Alpha]) m2 Sin[\[Theta]12]^2) + 
      E^(2 I \[Beta]) m3 Sin[\[Theta]13]^2) (E^(2 I \[Delta])
        Cos[\[Theta]23]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]23]^2) + 
   E^(I \[Delta])
     Sin[\[Theta]23] ((m1 - 
         E^(2 I \[Alpha])
           m2) Cos[\[Theta]12] Cos[\[Theta]23] Sin[\[Theta]12] + 
      E^(I \[Delta]) (-E^(2 I \[Beta]) m3 + m1 Cos[\[Theta]12]^2 + 
         E^(2 I \[Alpha])
           m2 Sin[\[Theta]12]^2) Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]23]) \
(Cos[\[Theta]13] (Cos[2 \[Theta]23] Cot[2 \[Theta]13] - 
         2 Cot[2 \[Theta]23]) + 
      6 ArcSin[
        2 \[Theta]23] Cos[\[Theta]23] Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]23] \
+ 2 E^(2 I \[Delta]) Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]23]^2 - 
      3 E^(I \[Delta]) Cot[2 \[Theta]12] Sin[2 \[Theta]23]) - 
   E^(I \[Delta])
     Cos[\[Theta]23] (E^(I \[Delta])
        Cos[\[Theta]23] (E^(2 I \[Beta]) m3 - m1 Cos[\[Theta]12]^2 - 
         E^(2 I \[Alpha])
           m2 Sin[\[Theta]12]^2) Sin[\[Theta]13] + (m1 - 
         E^(2 I \[Alpha])
           m2) Cos[\[Theta]12] Sin[\[Theta]12] Sin[\[Theta]23]) (Cos[\
\[Theta]13] (Cos[2 \[Theta]23] Cot[2 \[Theta]13] - 
         2 Cot[2 \[Theta]23]) + 
      4 ArcSin[
        2 \[Theta]23] Cos[\[Theta]23] Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]23] \
+ 2 E^(2 I \[Delta]) Sin[\[Theta]13] Sin[\[Theta]23]^2 - 
      2 E^(I \[Delta]) Cot[2 \[Theta]12] Sin[2 \[Theta]23]))```


Collect[expr, {m1, m2,  m3}].

Assuming that "expr" contains your expression and that all terms contain either m1,m2 or m3, you may use the command "Coefficient":
Coefficient[exp, #] & /@ {m1, m2, m3} // Simplify



Or CoefficientRules[exp, {m1, m2, m3}] to be extra-safe.
